# Cumulative Sum in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I was trying to use the inits function to create a function  that does:

```
 [x1,x2,x3,x4,x5....] ==  [0,x1, x1+x2, x1+x2+x3, x1+x2+x3+x4, (x1+x2+x3+x4+x5) ....]
```

this is my attempt:

```
sums:: [Int]->[Int]
sums (x:xs)  = [x] ++ map foldr 0 (+)  initial xs


inits1:: [int] -> [[int]]
inits1 []     = [[]]
inits1 (x:xs) = [[x]] ++ map (x:) (initial xs)
```

Comment: You need to add parenthesis around the pattern `x:xs` (i.e., `sums (x:xs) = ...`).

Comment: now I am getting more mistakes.. :(

Comment: `scanl` already does what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `inits` is a bad way of doing it.

Think about it. If you were doing it on paper, you wouldn't add up the first number, then the first two, then the first three, then the first four.

This is silly because when you add the first four you have to re-add the first three, even when you've already added them before.

Instead, what you'd just start adding them up, keeping a total and these totals would form you results.

So you should be using `scanl1`, which is like `foldl1` but gives you the results as it goes:

```
sums = scanl (+) 0
```

Avoiding the library functions shows better how it should be done (and roughly how `scanl` operates:

```
sums2 ls = sums_worker 0 ls where
  sums_worker acc (l:ls) = acc:(sums_worker (acc + l) ls)
  sums_worker acc [] = [acc]
```

Comment: Pedantic mode on: The author wanted sums to start with 0. :-)

Comment: nice. You haven't used any library function ? sums_worker is a function that gets what ? what is "acc (l:ls)" ? could you add the deceleration please ?

Comment: "acc" is the current sum. (l:ls) is the list, l being the first element and ls being the rest.

Answer (score 4):

Can you use the standard library?

```
sums :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
sums = scanl (+) 0
```

Answer (score 1):

`inits` will give all the initial segments of a list, and `sum` will give the sum of a list of number, so your `sums` could be defined like this:

```
sums = map sum . inits
```

Example

```
> sums [1..10]
[0,1,3,6,10,15,21,28,36,45,55]
```